# Not able to pass props in reactstrap's modal header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

I am passing props from MainCard component to ModalClass component. The problem is I am getting the props in before the Modal tag but when I call props in the Modal Header tag of Modal, it is not passing

In order to check whether I am getting the props in my ModalClass, I call the props before the button component in ModalClass component, and it confirms that the props are passing to the ModalClass component. But, when I try to do same in Modal header , it is not showing anything

What I did was:

```
    class ModalClass extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {

            }
        }
        render() {

            const { toggle, modal, buttonLabel, buttonclass, color } = this.props

            return (

                <React.Fragment>
               {this.props.top}   
// it showed me that the ModalClass is getting the props, I got the text "Hello" from the Payhead component
                    <Button color={color} onClick={toggle} className={buttonclass}>
                        <i className={this.props.class}>  </i> {buttonLabel}
                    </Button>
```

//PayHead component

```
import React from 'react';

const Payhead = () => {

    return (

        <React.Fragment> 
            hello
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default Payhead;
```

//MainCard component

Here, I am passing props to ModalClass component

```
state={
modal:false
}

    handleToggle = () => {
        this.setState({
            modal: !this.state.modal
        });

    }


render(){
return(


                        <ModalClass buttonLabel="Pay" class="fa fa-coins"
                            buttonclass="card-footer-item btn-lg rounded-0"
                            color="success" modal={this.state.modal} toggle={this.handleToggle} top={<Payhead />} />
)
}
```

//MODALCLASS component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from 'reactstrap';


class ModalClass extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

        }
    }
    render() {

        const { toggle, modal, buttonLabel, buttonclass, color } = this.props

        return (

            <React.Fragment>

                <Button color={color} onClick={toggle} className={buttonclass}>
                    <i className={this.props.class}>  </i> {buttonLabel}
                </Button>


                <Modal isOpen={modal} toggle={toggle} className="modal-dialog modal-drawer-right">
                    <ModalHeader toggle={toggle}>
                        {this.props.top}
                    </ModalHeader>
                    <ModalBody>
                     I am a test modal
                    </ModalBody>
                    <ModalFooter>
                        <Button color="primary" onClick={toggle} >
                               Do Something   </Button>{' '}
                        <Button color="secondary" onClick={toggle}>Cancel</Button>
                    </ModalFooter>
                </Modal>
            </React.Fragment>

        );
    }
}
export default ModalClass;
```

I expect it to show me the Payhead component but it's not showing it.

I am expecting that when I call `{this.props.top}` in Modal header, it should hit the Payhead component which I am passing as a property.

Comment: Your code is working fine.

Comment: @ravibagul91thanks for your response 

 yes I just saw that I had called ModalClass component twice in the MainCard Component and when I rremoved one of them and was left with a single ModalClass component, code worked fine..
Stiil don't know why it was'nt working when I had called ModalClass twice.
If I needed to call the ModalClass component twice, then this problem would still be there